# excel 2010 edit multiple hyperlinks VBA, macro

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

...a simple question (for some :)

the goal is to change a part of hyperlinks in a range of cells

- sheet 'Progress'
- range 'd9:d38'

hyperlinks now (rc001 is in D9; rc002 in D10 and so on)

`..\..\..\..\..\..\..\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\VNHS2_Reconciliation_report_RC001.xlsx`

hyperlinks to be

```
VNHS2_Reconciliation_report_RC001.xlsx (rc001 increasing by 1 up to 030)
```

anyone? pretty please :)

Comment: Do u mean in the same cell...???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple loop with basic string replacement.  I define a base Hyperlink address:

```
Const sFile As String = "..\..\..\..\..\..\..\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\VNHS2_Reconciliation_report_RC000.xlsx"
```

And then use the `Replace` method to change the `000` part to `001`, `002`, etc., for each cell.

```
Sub Foo()
Const sFile As String = "..\..\..\..\..\..\..\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\VNHS2_Reconciliation_report_RC000.xlsx"
Dim rngLinks As Range: Set rngLinks = Range("D9:D38")
Dim cl As Range
Dim i As Integer

For Each cl In rngLinks
    i = i + 1
    cl.Hyperlinks.Add cl, Replace(sFile, "000", Format(i, "00#"))

Next



End Sub
```

Comment: Good stuff, David. I also need to change the first part of the link "..\..\..\..\..\..\..\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\" into e.g. "..Design\Reconciliation_reports\2 Internal project deliverables" How to approach that?

Comment: Will all links be in the same directory?  If so, you can just update the line `Const sFile As String...` to reflect the directory path. Make sure you include the trailing backslash.